# How to Get APK Directly from PlayStore (Not using any other sites)

Tags: android, download, google-play, apk

I would like to build something like which [apkmirror.com](https://apkmirror.com) does.

My query is **how does apkmirror gets apks ?** and **is there a way or even a system design which allows us to download/extract an apk from playstore directly ?**

*Please don't comment any 3rdparty websites :)*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question is closed.

I had automated the android emulator with ADB (Android Debugging Bridge) and using the ADB itself the APK is copied to host machine.

I am building a NodeJS based package for this which will be soon released in npm.

Thanks!